# Falha ao reiniciar o Firebird pelo PHP

Tags: php, firebird-2.5

Tenho um servidor virtual com sistema operacional Linux-Debian, que o mesmo é configurado como servidor Web Nginx e banco de dados Firebird. Possuo um script que realiza uma rotina de reinicialização do Firebird e o executo quando ocorre algum travamento. Meu script, que fica localizado em: '/scripts/restart_firebird.sh' consigo executá-lo normalmente por SSH. Surgiu a necessidade de colocar o script para rodar através de uma solicitação através de um script em PHP. O comando utilizado é:

```
$output = shell_exec("/scripts/restart_firebird.sh");
echo $output;
```

Ao executar, recebo a mensagem:

> Stopping Firebird 2.5 superclassic server...failed.

Verifiquei nos arquivos de log do firebird localizados em '/var/log' mas não está sendo registrado este erro.

Conteúdo do script sh:

> service firebird2.5-superclassic restart

Comment: Deve ser algum problema com as permissões do usuário do nginx ao tentar executar o script. Para ter certeza, tente logar com o usuário do seu nginx no servidor e executar o script.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr, o usuário do nginx é o 'www-data'. Tentei executar o script pelo SSH com este usuário e a mensagem de erro que mostra é: service: not found. Como eu poderia dar permissão à este usuário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples de executar um script da forma que você precisa é utilizando o **[`visudo`](http://sejalivre.org/aprendendo-a-usar-e-configurar-o-sudo/)**. Mas veja esta é apenas uma forma, sugiro que você entenda melhor o funcionamento das permissões no Linux, e o uso do `visudo` de forma incorreta pode causar problemas de segurança no seu servidor.

```
$visudo
```

Seria como abaixo, irá permitir a execução sem pedir senha:

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /scripts/restart_firebird.sh
```

Comment: No Debian, qual seria o comando similar que tenha o mesmo efeito? Pois visudo ou sudo são comandos desconhecidos.

Comment: Realizando mais umas tentativas, descobri que o caso é mais sério. Na verdade o usuário www-data pode executar o script sh. O que ele está sem permissão é de manipular serviços em si. Eu teria que adicionar o www-data ao grupo root?

Comment: Como eu disse antes entenda bem como funcionam as permissões de execução do linux. Não é seguro você colocar o www-data no grupo do root.

Comment: Compreendido. Vejo que a solução seria executar o comando informando o usuário root. Pesquisando, encontrei o seguinte comando: `su -c "comando" -s /bin/sh root`. Só que a senha do usuário root é solicitada. É possível acrescentar a senha na linha de comando?

Comment: realmente você tinha razão, todo o problema estava relacionado a permissões do usuário "www-data". Tive que fazer umas alterações... Primeiro instalei e configurei o "sudo" e modifique o comando para: `sudo -H -u www-data bash -c '/etc/init.d/firebird2.5-superclassic restart'`. Pois com "service firebird2.5-superclassic restart" não estava reconhecendo.